# count in while loop in tkinter - guess game (word)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a guess the word game in Python and I'm trying to add counting in the game, in the while loop.

Somehow I found a trick to add a while loop within the main loop and the game is working almost perfectly, except the counting method I tried to add to the game.

I don't know why but it only counts in the first round when the game is started and then gets stuck on "9".

When I built the game without the GUI it worked!

```py
while "_" in empty or count < 10:
    count += 1
    letter = str(e.get())
    if letter in word:
        letter = e.get()
        for i in range(0, len(word)):
            if letter == word[i]:
                empty[i] = letter
                e.delete(0, END)
                text = Label(root, text=f"good guess you have more {10 - count} tries")
                text.grid(row=5, column=0)
                result = Label(root, text=f'the words is \n {empty} \n Guess a letter')
                result.grid(row=3, column=0)

    if letter not in word:
        e.delete(0, END)
        text = Label(root, text=f"wrong guess you have more {10 - count} tries")
        text.grid(row=5, column=0)
        result = Label(root, text=f'the words is \n {empty} \n Guess a letter')
        result.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: In every loop of the while loop the count need to add +1 (the count is var  above the while loop and now equal to 0), and in evey try the count need to add +1 until it got to 10 and break out from the loop..

Comment: @Sujay btw, just in case You didn't know You could have just typed: "Please provide a \[mre]" which would be basically the same exact You wrote except it would link to the explanation of what is a mre (there are other shortcuts too). For the OP however I would like to say that loops are not meant for tkinter ("`.after()`" loops are sth else), in tkinter You should have callbacks that handlle everything

Comment: @Matiiss I didn't know about those, thanks. For anyone else, the full list is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @Henry You can also simply press the "Help" button when adding comments, You can go from there then